# Calculate determinant of the power of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am given a square matrix $A$ with determinant $-t$. My professor asks what’s the determinant of $\text{det}(A^{2020})$.

This is what I’ve done:

$$\text{det}(A^{2020})=(-1)^{2020}\text{det}(A)=-t$$

I’ve used $\text{det}(A^n)=(-1)^n \text{det}(A)$

This is what my professor worked out:

$$\text{det}(A^{2020})=\text{det}(A)^{2020}=(-t)^{2020}=t^{2020}$$

Are they both valid?

Comment: What you have done is not correct and I have no idea how you get that answer. Can you explain what you have done?

Comment: Updated question with formula

Comment: $det(A^{n})=(-1)^{n} det (A)$ is very strange. Where did you get this from?

Comment: And how on earth can both answers be correct?

Comment: Whoever told you that $\det(A^n)=(-1)^n\det(A)$, you shouldn't listen to that person next time. (Let $n=1$:  your formula says $\det(A)=-\det(A)$.  So every matrix has determinant zero...)

Comment: Sorry, I took wrong notes on that part. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\det(A^m)=(\det(A))^m$, The answer should be $t^{2020}$. Your  Prof. is  right.

Comment: Corrected it now.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to believe that *somehow*  $\;A^{2020}=(-1)^{2020}A\;$ , which is certainly false. What your prof. wrote is right. You are **not** multiplying by $\;-1\;$ the matrix $\;A\;$ ...!

Don't let that minus sign in $\;-t\;$ fool you. What you must realize is that is **always** true that $\;\det(A^k)=(\det A)^k\;$ ...that's all.